# How to Update An Ionic Project From 1.X to 3.X

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an ionic project, created with Ionic Version *'1.7.12'* (returns it with `$ ionic --version` command).

When I run `$ ionic lib` on project folder, it returns;

`Local Ionic version: 1.3.1  (/tmp/project-name/www/lib/ionic/version.json)
Latest Ionic version: 1.3.3  (released 2017-02-24)`

[Project folder Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYV9O.png)

---

**My main goal is to convert this project's Ionic version into the latest Ionic Framework version.** I looked up, but most of the guides covers how to convert from 2.X to 3.X [such as this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/guide-how-to-update-to-ionic-3-x/87516).
Also, I can't run this project with `$ ionic serve` command on a computer has Ionic version *'3.4.0'*, but no other issue with *''*

Any information about how to convert this project into Ionic Version 3.4.0 is much appreciated.

Comment: you need to downgrade your ionic/cli to 1.x for running the app using ionic serve command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic version v1 - v2 was a major upgrade using ES6 and typescript, amoungst other upgrades. The differences are major and there is no way (I know) to do this other than creating a brand new project, because the structure of the app is completely different.

I suggest you follow the official guide on migration from v1 to v2.

http://ionicframework.com/files/Ionic2Migration.pdf

Then use the guide you found to upgrade it to v3 as v2 -> v3 version upgrade is rather smaller.

Comment: I think that RedCrusador is right. I started a new project.

Comment: Thank you RedCrusador, ACES. I am also planning to start over.